# CUPS driver for HP laserjet CP1525nw

Tags: cups

I just got my CUPS server setup, and I really like it. I have my other black and white printers working fine on it. When installing my HP LaserJet CP1525nw I got it ready to install on windows. I cant find the correct .inf file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To install HP LaserJet CP1525nw drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install task-print-server
sudo apt-get install cups
sudo apt-get install skanlite cups cups-client cups-filters system-config-printer
sudo apt-get install skanlite system-config-printer
sudo apt-get install hplip printer-driver-hpijs
```

Add yourself to the lpadmin group

```
sudo adduser yourusername lpadmin
```

Log out and back in, and then run

```
service cups start
```

and then plug in USB port.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/cp1525nw-and-mis-leading-selling/td-p/416257) it should work with hplip using the "HP Color LaserJet Series PCL 6 CUPS (color)" driver.